# C++ When executting recursive Fast Fourier Transformation the program exits not reaching the end

Tags: c++, algorithm, fft

I am working of the FFT (Fast fourier transformation) algorithm and I want to execute the program on bigger data sets to test the efficiency of the algorithm. However when increasing the input data to a higher value than `65536` the recursive algorithm stops mid-way not once reachin the end of the recursion.

I have tried to run the program on `200000` input entries however the algorithm stoped without any error. I also tried debugging the program with gdb however i am not sure how to interpret the debugger results.

This is the program i am using:

```cpp
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <chrono>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

const double PI = 3.141592653589793238460;

typedef complex<double> cd;
typedef vector<cd> vcd;

void fft(vcd& a) {
    int n = a.size();
    cout << a.size() << endl;
    if (n <= 1) return;

    vcd a0(n / 2), a1(n / 2);
    for (int i = 0; 2 * i < n; i++) {
        a0[i] = a[2*i];
        a1[i] = a[2*i + 1];
    }

    fft(a0);
    fft(a1);

    double ang = 2 * PI / n;
    cd w(1), wn(cos(ang), sin(ang));
    for (int i = 0; 2 * i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = a0[i] + w * a1[i];
        a[i + n/2] = a0[i] - w * a1[i];
        w *= wn;
    }
}

int main() {
    ifstream dataFile("data.txt");
    string line;
    vcd data;

    if (!dataFile.is_open()) {
        cout << "Couldn't open the file" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    cout << "Loading data" << endl;
    while (getline(dataFile, line)) {
        stringstream ss(line);
        double val;
        ss >> val;
        data.push_back(val);
    }

    dataFile.close();

    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    cout << "Calculating fft" << endl;
    fft(data);

    auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop - start);

    cout << "FFT result: " << endl;
    // for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
        // cout << data[i] << endl;

    cout << "Time taken FFT: " << duration.count() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This is the program i use to generate the input:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

const double PI = 3.141592653589793238460;

int main() {
    // int N = 200000; // stops
    int N = 65536; // works
    ofstream dataFile("data.txt");

    if (!dataFile.is_open()) {
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        double dataPoint = 0.5 * sin(2 * PI * 5 * i / N) + 0.5 * sin(2 * PI * 10 * i / N) + 0.3 * sin(2 * PI * 20 * i / N);
        dataFile << dataPoint << endl;
    }

    dataFile.close();
    cout << "Data saved" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output i get when the program stops abruptly without reaching the end:

```bash
PS C:\Users\user\proj> ./a.exe
Loading data
Calculating fft
200000
100000
50000
25000
12500
6250
3125
1562
781
PS C:\Users\user\proj>
```

Comment: `vcd a0(n / 2), a1(n / 2); for (int i = 0; 2 * i < n; i++) { a0[i] = a[2*i];` This accesses an index out of bounds when `n` is odd. In that case, `2*i < n` is equivalent to `i <= n/2`

Comment: Thanks a lot @IgorTandetnik that fixed my issue. But why didn't I get any error messages related to accessing an index out of bounds?

Comment: Because you're using [`operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) instead of [`at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at).

Comment: Thank you!!
If you don't mind answering, why would they make the vectors to work this way?

Comment: @zarky The designers did not want the overhead of bounds checking.  See the [Zero-overhead principle](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/Zero-overhead_principle).  If you want bounds-checking with `[]`, you have to write the code to do this, or use `at()`, which has bounds checking.

Comment: Also, using `[]` when going out-of-bounds is *undefined behavior*.  So the same code you wrote but using a different compiler or set of compiler options could have also crashed.  For Visual C++ running a debug version, an assert() dialog would have popped up, since Visual C++ added bounds checking to debug builds (not release builds).

Comment: @zarky I suggest running your original code with the bug, but use `at()`, just to get familiar with the type of error messages you will get when you go out-of-bounds.  You will get a `std::out_of_range` exception thrown.

Comment: Unrelated: Don't use `std::high_resolution_clock` to make measurements. It may not be monotonic. Use `std::steady_clock`.